# I don't install angular 4 width angular-froala-wysiwyg. who can help me?

Tags: angular

I don't install angular 4 width angular-froala-wysiwyg. It notify a error that  "

1. Metadata version mismatch for module
   C:/Users/Thanhtung/Desktop/abitstore/abitstore.vn/node_modules/angular-froala-wysiwyg/index.d.ts,
   found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in
   C:/Users/Thanhtung/Desktop/abitstore/abitstore.vn/src/app/app.module.ts,
   resolving symbol AppModule in
   C:/Users/Thanhtung/Desktop/abitstore/abitstore.vn/src/app/app.module.ts,
   resolving symbol AppModule in
   C:/Users/Thanhtung/Desktop/abitstore/abitstore.vn/src/app/app.module.ts
       at syntaxError (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
       at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
       at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
       at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
       at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
       at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
       at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
       at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:241:66)
       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\Thanhtung\Desktop\abitstore\abitstore.vn\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:495:24)
       at

   ". who can help me ?

Comment: try installing angular4 instead of angular5

Comment: I don't usage angular 5 because my project using a theme https://adminlte.io/ that only usage angular 4

Comment: oh, it might be the angular-froala-wysiwyg module - roll that back to a version that depends on angular4

Comment: don't find instruct install version that depends on angular 4 at document and I searched google that don't find. can you  say a  clear solution of it for me

Answer (score 1):

use some Styles in your post that people can understand better actually i can't identify where is path's/codes or your writting